# Moving prefab to various position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab that I want to move to various position in scene, for example, move to: North, South, East and West in a determined time until the player collided.

how can I do this ?

I'm trying this

```
//time prefab
private float timeChange = 0f;
private float timeChangeDelay = 1f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
     changePrefabPosition();
}

private void changePrefabPosition()
{        
     timeChange += Time.deltaTime;        

     // north = 1, south = -1, east = 1, west = -1
     int[] northSouth = {1, -1};
     int[] westEast = {-1, 1};

     if(timeChange >= timeChangeDelay)
     {
          int index = Random.Range(0, northSouth.Length);   
          transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, 
                               new Vector2(westEast[index],
                               northSouth[index]), 0.1f * Time.deltaTime);
          timeChange = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Use Instantiate(...) function, there is a parameter to set the position of the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Instantiate the prefab before you can move it. The simplest way is to load the prefab to a public variable in the Editor by drag and drop.

```
public class ObjectCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

Then the code inside the Prefab:

```
public class PrefabCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    void Awake()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Then just use `transform` to move your instantiated object around.

---

You say your Sprite doesn't move. However, it does move, but by tiny decimal amounts because of the way you defined the movement.

Change: `0.1f * Time.deltaTime`

To: `2f * Time.deltaTime`

Your object moves. From your post I really can't tell if it is meant to be like that or with longer paths. If you want longer paths then you need to define coordinates for North, South, West, and East.

Comment: I understand, but if I add this script into a gameobject directly after create a prefab with this gameobject and after use instantiate ?

Comment: You can add the `PrefabCode` to the prefab that you plan to instantiate. So that after instantiation your new object will have that script attached.

Comment: Try this: `transform.position = new Vector3(500, 500, 0);` Tell me it doesn't move, lol.

Comment: I'm using Vector2D because is a 2D game and I'm still using Lerp also. Look at my post how I'm trying!

Comment: @FernandoPaiva Look at my edit, your object moves. From your post I really can't tell if it is meant to be like that or with longer paths.